# Socket.IO Performance Oddities

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, socket.io

I've been running a few tests to figure out the fastest way to send a specific data using latest Socket.IO version (v1.4.5).

I tried passing an object, a string, a Uint8Array and a Buffer. I'm excluding the time to generate that the formatted data.

```
    var d = Date.now();

    var obj = {"q":"-dgn,pqUsY","u":{"Gm5SP":[1109,1001],"t9sck":[2026],"hpcM8":[1407,841],"DNB7S":[1285,478],"PV7Dt":[2043,986,31]}};
    var objStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
    var objUint8 = new Uint8Array(objStr.length);
    for(var i = 0 ; i < objStr.length; i++)
        objUint8[i] = objStr[i].charCodeAt(i);
    var objBuffer = new Buffer(objUint8);       

    for(var i = 0 ; i < 20000; i++){
        if(num === 0)
            socket.emit('a',obj);               
        if(num === 1)
            socket.emit('a',objStr);                
        if(num === 2)
            socket.emit('a',objUint8);              
        if(num === 3)
            socket.emit('a',objBuffer);             
    }

    console.log(Date.now() - d);
```

Results:

Object: 244ms
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          String: 126ms
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Uint8Array: 1292ms
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Buffer: 212ms

Why is Uint8Array so slow? Isn't it really similar to NodeJS Buffer? Shouldn't the Buffer be faster than the String?

Comment: websockets protocol can handle buffers but Uint8Array needs serialization to ship.

Comment: How different is a Uint8Array and buffer? Isn't Uint8Array a ArrayBuffer which is a Buffer? In the memory, aren't they structured the same way?

Comment: idk about in ram (depend on engine), but over the wire the aren't the same. it also possible that socket.io doesn't send them in the most efficient way.